# error when call the class inside in statefullWidget flutter-web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

when I use this code output in my browser Assertion failed: is not true. usually like this because the data is not sent to the list view, right ?? but what's the wrong part ??

> > ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> >     following assertion was thrown building ItemActivity(dirty): Assertion
> >     failed: is not true

this is my code when calling for API

```
          FutureBuilder(
              future: UserController.getActivity(_selectedUser),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? new ItemActivity(
                        list: snapshot.data,
                      )
                    : new Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
              }),
```

and this code I have at the bottom of the page, really outside the widget

```
 class ItemActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  final List list;
  ItemActivity({this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        Map<String, dynamic> activity = list[i]['activity'];
        return new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                title: Text(activity.containsKey("project")
                    ? activity["project"]
                    : "-"),
                subtitle: Text("created at : ${list[i]['created_at']}"),
              )),
            ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the constructor of your ItemActivity() to this:

```
ItemActivity({Key key, this.list}) : super(key: key);
```